# XSLT / XML select value by name

Tags: xml, xslt

New to `XSLT`, but have a scenario below. I am trying to get the GroupControlNumber value of `'ABCDE'` in my `XSLT`, but can't figure out how to call it by name.

Here's a snippet of the XML

```html
<Transactions>
  <Transaction Status="Accepted">
    <IdentifierName>TransactionControlNumber</IdentifierName>
    <TransactionNumber>0001</TransactionNumber>
    <Identifiers>
      <Envelope IdentifierName="ControlNumber" IdentifierValue="12345" />
      <Envelope IdentifierName="GroupControlNumber" IdentifierValue="ABCDE" />
      <Envelope IdentifierName="OriginatorId" IdentifierValue="!@#$%" />
    </Identifiers>
  </Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

Here's what I got so far on the XSLT side

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../../Identifiers/Envelope/@IdentifierValue"/>
```

But this gives me all three identifier values. I understand why I get all 3, just looking to filter it.

```
Output
12345 ABCDE !@#$%
```

```
Desired output
ABCDE
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your `xpath`.

```
//Transactions/Transaction/Identifiers/Envelope[@IdentifierName='GroupControlNumber'][1]/@IdentifierValue
```

Comment: I did not know you could access by index! This is great! Thank you ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ